# React Native - unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I  have a problem understanding where this error came from. 
The console says:

**Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method in LoginScreen.**

I tried the trick with _isMounted - doesn't work.

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            errorMessage: null,
            logOut: false,
        };
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    handleLogin() {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            const { email, password } = this.state;
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .catch(errorMessage => this.setState({errorMessage}));

            this.props.navigation.navigate("Direction", { email, password });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.greeting}>
                    Log in
                </Text>

                <View style={styles.form}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>
                            Email
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input}
                                   autoCapitalize="none"
                                   onChangeText={ email => this.setState({email})}
                                   value={this.state.email}>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>
                            Password
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input}
                                   secureTextEntry
                                   autoCapitalize="none"
                                   onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                                   value={this.state.password}>
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>

                    <Text style={styles.error}>
                        { this.state.errorMessage &&
                            <Text style={styles.error}>
                                Incorrect login or password
                            </Text>
                        }
                    </Text>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                                      onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>
                        Log in
                    </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <View style={styles.register}>
                        <Text style={{color: "grey"}}>
                            Don't have an Account
                        </Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.secondButton}
                                          onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("Register")}}>
                            <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>
                                Registration
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is coming from your `handleLogin` method, with the main catch being that `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise. This means that the flow is as follows:

1. User presses login button, and `handleLogin` is executed.
2. Component is still mounted at this point so flow will enter `if (this._isMounted)`.
3. `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise, so if there is an error, the catch block won't be executed immediately.
4. You then navigate away from the current component, resulting in the component being unmounted.
5. The catch block of `signInWithEmailAndPassword` *now* is executed (if there was an error), where it tries to update the state of the component which is at this point unmounted -> boom, the console warning you are seeing.

Depending on the flow you are going for, you could probably resolve this by having the navigation be in a `then` block following `signInWithEmailAndPassword` like so:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
               .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Direction", { email, password }))
               .catch(errorMessage => this.setState({errorMessage}));
```

But do note that this will mean you won't navigate away in case of an error.